# Can't get Laravel associate to work

Tags: php, laravel, relational-database, eloquent, relationship

I'm not quite sure if I understand the [associate](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#inserting-related-models) method in Laravel. I understand the idea, but I can't seem to get it to work.

With this (distilled) code:

```
class User
{

    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Customer');
    }

}

class Customer
{

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

}

$user = new User($data);
$customer = new Customer($customerData);

$user->customer()->associate($customer);
```

I get a `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::associate()` when I try to run this.

From what I can read, I do it exactly as is stated in the docs.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I have to admit that when I first started using Laravel the relationships where the part that I had to consistently refer back to the docs for and even then in some cases I didn't quite get it right.

To help you along, `associate()` is used to update a `belongsTo()` relationship. Looking at your code, the returned class from `$user->customer()` is a `hasOne` relationship class and will not have the associate method on it.

If you were to do it the other way round.

```
$user = new User($data);
$customer = new Customer($customerData);

$customer->user()->associate($user);
$customer->save();
```

It would work as `$customer->user()` is a `belongsTo` relationship.

To do this the other way round you would first save the user model and then save the customer model to it like:

```
$user = new User($data);
$user->save();

$customer = new Customer($customerData);
$user->customer()->save($customer);
```

Edit: It may not be necessary to save the user model first but I've just always done that, not sure why.

Comment: Yes, your first thing seems to work correctly. I think it's kinda odd that it has to work that way around. Anyhoe, thanks. And so that you may learn something new: $user->push(); saves the user and all it's relationships.

Comment: I noticed that we need to do `$customer->save()` after `->associate($something)`

Comment: in other words, User class hosts/has the Customer. So that we can associate/disassociate the user to/off a given customer like `$customer->user()->associate($user)` or `$customer->user()->associate()`, next to `$customer->save()`

Comment: You can also directly save after the association like this `$customer->user()->associate($user)->save();`

Answer (score 10):

As I understand it, `->associate()` can onyl be called on a BelongsTo relationship. So, in your example, you *could* do `$customer->user()->associate($user)`. However, in order to 'associate' a Has* relationship you use `->save()`, so your code should be `$user->customer()->save($customer)`

Comment: having same problem. but on belongToMany() relation. 
how could I fix this? 
thanks

Comment: For many-to-many methods (see docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) you use `->attach()` and `->detach()`. E.g. `$post->tags()->attach($tag);` Now, officially, the attach and detach method only accept IDs, but when I tested this some time ago on 4.x, you could pass actual models in. That may have changed for 5.x.

Comment: this kinda working. but its asking for an array, and i'm getting object instead.

Comment: I think your best course of action here is to ask a new question specific to your problem. Include the version of Laravel you are using and any relevant code and I'm sure you will get the help you need.

Answer (score 0):

just add `->save()` to the end.

`$user->customer()->associate($customer)->save();`