# Laravel eloquent: store new model with related new models

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

i'm tryint to store a new Model, with many related new models.

I have my **Service** model

```
class Service extends Model{
    public function serviceoperations() {
        return $this->hasMany("App\Models\ServiceOperation");
    }
}
```

and my **ServiceOperation** model

```
class ServiceOperation extends Model{
    public function service() {
        return $this->belongsTo("App\Models\Service");
    }
}
```

in my **store** function i'm creating a new service model, with many serviceoperation models, using a **transaction**:

```
use App\Models\Service;
use App\Models\ServiceOperation;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

    public function store(Request $request) {
        $service = new Service();
        $ops = [];
        foreach ($operations as $operation) {
            $op = new ServiceOperation();
            $ops[] = $op;
        }
        DB::transaction(function()use($service, $ops) {
            $service->save();
            $service->serviceoperations()->saveMany($ops);
        });
    }
```

My **Question** is: Is there another way to add my new related *serviceoperation* models to my new *service* model, and persist them in the database in a single command?

Answer (score 0):

You must use [associate](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships) method.

```
$service->serviceoperations()->associate($serviceoperations)
```

Hope it help you :)

Comment: i'm not sure it works. looking at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26160661/cant-get-laravel-associate-to-work) i should save my service model before i can call the associate.
Anyway, i just tried it and it doesn't work. I also tried the reverse `$operation->service()->associate($service)`, but it doesn't save the new operations created.