# Associate() in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, associate

I have 2 models, a User and an Address. I am still experimenting on associate() since I read it in https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships but I'm having some trouble with implementing it and sadly my video tutorial doesn't cover the associate() function.

```
class User extends Authenticatable
      public function address() {
      return $this->hasOne('App\Address');
}

class Address extends Model
      public function user() {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

// --web.php--

Route::get('/sample',function(){
$user = User::create(['name'=>'user 1','email'=>'user@laravel.com',password='']);
$address = Address::create(['name'=>'sample address of user 1']);

$address->user()->associate($user);

});
```

Everything was saved, but I was expecting that user_id of the address would be 1. Instead, user_id of the address was set to NULL. Isn't associate() suppose to link a specific 'belongsTo' model to its parent by automatically assigning the foreign key equal to the parent's ID? BTW im very new to PHP and Laravel so yeah..

Comment: Hi! Try adding `$address->save();` afterwards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't get Laravel associate to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26160661/cant-get-laravel-associate-to-work)

Answer (score 5):

You still need to `save` the object to store the value.

As the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models) says:

> ### Belongs To Relationships
>
> When updating a belongsTo relationship, you may use the associate
> method. This method will set the foreign key on the child model:
>
> ```php
> $account = App\Account::find(10);
>
> $user->account()->associate($account);
>
> $user->save();
> ```

So, as you can see, after associate it:

```php
$address->user()->associate($user);
```

you need to save it:

```php
$address->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Address model would need to have a belongsTo User relationship.
eg:

```
class Address extends Model
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Note: You would need to make sure you had a foreign key constraint

eg Migration:

```
Schema::table('addresses', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');

    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
});
```

Comment: It already has a BelongsTo relationship, it was indicated above.. I just had a typo error when I wrote the code here.. sorry

Comment: Sorry, I don't see where you have a User relationship in your Address model.

Comment: Re edited the code in this post. Another typo error when I was writing the code here.

Comment: @JpArcilla, CUGReen is right, the Address model doesn't have the user() function, and in your web file you are trying to access it

Comment: Did you set up the foreign key constraints in your migration/database?